# Hypothesis Testing Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics

I am unsure how to approach this problem:

Consider a random variable, X. Our hypothesis is that X~N(0,1) or X is standard normal distribution.

If we observe that X = 2.2. What is the likelihood of this hypothesis. Would the hypothesis be rejeted if we wanted to maintain a specificity of .95?

Thanks,
RH

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by $X=2.2$? $X$ is a continuous random variable and hence the prob that takes on a particular value is zero...perhaps I am missing your point in the question...could you clarify it please?

Comment: I think the question is terribly worded. I believe that X = 2.2 means that an observation on X was recorded to be 2.2.

Comment: Ok. But even so, what do you plan to do with a single observation?

Comment: You should try to explain better your problem! In hypothesis testing we usually have two hypothesis, the null and the alternative. Then you can compute things such as the likelihood ratio. But you did not give any alternative hypothesis, so we cannot do that. This leaves us with very little to work on, so pleas explain better.

Comment: I think there are several imperfections in the way the question is phrased, but I completely disagree with the comments from Cristian and Rich H.  That particular detail was clearly expressed.  And I find Cristian's second comment somewhat obtuse.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I disagree. The question is not clear at all. First, the null is X normal; what is the alternative? X is chi-square? My guess was that Rich had in mind something along the lines of Dilip's answer. That's why I wrote my 1st comment. Rich then said that he believes X=2.2 is an observation on X, which  made me think that he is dealing with samples, in which case you need a sample larger than one to get estimates of the mean and the variance of X. This is why I wrote my 2nd comment. Sorry if you think this is obtuse.

Answer (score 2):

You have specified the *null* hypothesis that $X$ is a standard normal random variable. The *alternative* hypothesis is sometimes not specified explicitly,
though in simple examples of this kind, the alternative could be that $X$ is a 
unit-variance normal random variable with mean $\mu \neq 0$.
A typical question that needs to be resolved is:

> Given that we observed that $X$ has value $\alpha$,
>   is this observation consistent with the null hypothesis?

The idea here is that a standard normal random variable $X$
is quite unlikely to take on large positive or large 
negative values. With high probability, $X$ lies in the
interval $[-3,+3]$. So if we had observed $X = 10$, say,
we could quite confidently *reject* the null hypothesis
since the alternative, that the observation came from
a distribution with mean $\mu$ closer to $10$ looks
to a more reasonable assumption.  But even in the absence
of a specified (or vaguely specified or unspecified) alternative
hypothesis, the observation $X=10$ seems not very consistent
with the null hypothesis. This observation *could* occur
by chance even when the null hypothesis is true, but it is
our fondest hope we
hope that we have not been so unlucky when we confidently
*reject* the null hypothesis.

On the other hand, if $X = 0.1$, we would not be inclined
to reject the null hypothesis.  It is perfectly consistent
with $X$ being a standard normal variable.  But understand
that

> *not rejecting the null hypothesis* is **not** the same
>   as a whole-hearted embrace or *acceptance of the null
>   hypothesis.*

All you are saying when you fail to reject the null
is that the available evidence is not strong enough to
force you into consideration of alternatives.  Notice,
for example, that the observation $X=0.1$ is also
quite consistent with the hypothesis that $X$ is
a unit-variance normal random variable with mean
$0.00000001$, say, rather than the mean $0$ insisted
upon in the null hypothesis.

Now, turning to your specific problem,
$P\{|X| > 1.96\} = 0.05$ and so if you observe
that the observed value $\alpha$ of $X$ is outside
the interval $[-1.96,+1.96]$, you *reject* the null
hypothesis, while if $\alpha \in [-1.96,+1.96]$,
you do not reject the null hypothesis.
Your *confidence level* in this choice is
$0.95$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  With one observation, you should ask if there is at least a 5% chance you would see something this far from zero.  Look up your normal distribution table and see if 5% of the samples are this far from the center.